# How to sum up pandas columns where the number is determined by the values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Say we have a pandas dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,1,1,1,1],
                     [3,1,1,1,1,1]], 
                     columns=['number','value_1','value_2','value_3','value_4','value_5'] )
```

I want to get a new column by summing up the `value` columns based on the `number` column, the desired results will be 2 (value_1+value_2) for the first row and 3 (value_1+value_2+value_3) for the second row.

What is the most efficient way to code this for extremely large dataframe (numpy operation preferred)?